# Run sudo script without sudo password

Tags: bash, sudo, privileges, raspberry-pi3, sudoers

I'm trying to run script that is using sudo commands on profile that have set password on sudo.

I want to have 2 accounts, first will be original ***Pi*** account that I want to set password on sudo/root so no one will install or change anything. The second account will be ***admin*** that will have all permission and it will be use to all instalations and changes.

But I have 2 scripts on Pi account that need to be run with sudo.
One is running [Devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) script.
And another run Pidgin in loop and watch when it was closed and run it again.

Earlier I added both scripts to .profile file so they will run on start-up and it work perfectly, but when I added new account and change sudoers to require password for sudo it stops working.

For now i have done those things:

I've create new account ***admin*** and add him to ***sudo*** and ***adm*** group:

```
sudo adduser admin
sudo adduser admin sudo
sudo adduser admin adm
```

Next I've change a line in ***sudoers*** file from:

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

To this

```
pi ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL
```

I have made another script that will start those two scripts so I can remove them from .profile (I thought that it will help somehow).

Then I've added that script ***adm.sh*** to sudoers:

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/pi/adm.sh
```

and in another version

```
pi ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/pi/adm.sh
```

And this is not working.

I was looking for solution in Google but that what I found wasn't helpful form me.